# Find a marix of a linear transformation given its effect on vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

Im trying to find the matrix corresponding to this linear combination. I cant seem to get the right answer.

$T(1,0,0)^t=(1,0,0)^t$

$T(-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2,0)^t=(-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2,0)^t$

$T(-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2,0)^t=(-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2,0)^t$

p.s this the a reflection of a equatorial triangle with endpoints $(1,0,0)$, $(-1/2,\sqrt{3}/2,0)$, $(-1/2,-\sqrt{3}/2,0)$.

I would like to find the transformation matrix $T$ for this. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume

$$
T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} \\
t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} \\
t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix},
\quad a = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\quad b = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
\quad c = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix},
$$
so that 
$$
\begin{cases}
T\,a = a\\
T\, b = c \\
T\,c = b
\end{cases}
$$
then
$$
T\, a = a \iff
\begin{bmatrix}
t_{11} & t_{12} & t_{13} \\
t_{21} & t_{22} & t_{23} \\
t_{31} & t_{32} & t_{33} \\
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\implies
\begin{cases}
t_{11} = 1 \\
t_{21} = 0 \\
t_{31} = 0 
\end{cases}
\implies
T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & t_{12} & t_{13} \\
0 & t_{22} & t_{23} \\
0 & t_{32} & t_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad \qquad
$$
$$
T\, b = c \iff
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & t_{12} & t_{13} \\
0 & t_{22} & t_{23} \\
0 & t_{32} & t_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\implies
\begin{cases}
- \frac{1}{2}  + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} t_{12} = -\frac{1}{2} \\
\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} t_{22} = -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\
-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} t_{32} = 0 \\
\end{cases}
\implies \qquad \qquad 
\\ \implies 
\begin{cases}
t_{12} = 0 \\
t_{22} = -1  \\
t_{32} = 0 \\
\end{cases}
\implies T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & t_{13} \\
0 & -1 & t_{23} \\
0 & 0 & t_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
T\, b = c \iff
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & t_{13} \\
0 & -1 & t_{23} \\
0 & 0 & t_{33} 
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
= \begin{bmatrix} -\frac{1}{2} \\ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}
\quad -\quad
\text{does not give us any new information.}
$$

Note that from the data given it is impossible to determine values of $\,t_{13},\,\;t_{23}\,$ and $\,t_{33}.$ 
Let us assign to them arbitrary values $\,C_1, \;\,\ C_2\,$ and $\,C_3\,$ respectively.
Finally, we write the transformation matrix

$$
\bbox[5pt, border:solid 1.5pt #F00000]{
T = 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & C_1 \\
0 & -1 & C_2 \\
0 & 0 & C_3
\end{bmatrix}
}
$$

Comment: Thanks Vlad! I'll do this for the other 5 symmetries (well technically 4, ignoring the trivial symmetry)

Answer (score 1):

Let $T=(t_{ij})_{3\times 3}$.

One has $$\begin{cases}
t_{11} = 1,& t_{21} = 0,& t_{31} = 0;\\
\frac{-1}{2}t_{11} +\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t_{12} = -\frac{1}{2}, & \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t_{22} =-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t_{32} = 0; \\
\frac{-1}{2}t_{11} -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t_{12} = -\frac{1}{2}, & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t_{22} =\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}, & -\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}t_{32} = 0.
\end{cases}$$

So you have $$T=\begin{pmatrix}1&0&\ast \\0&-1&\ast\\0&0&\ast\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you, I know the final column is (0,0,-1) (just becuase this flip about the x axis invert's all y values and z values) but just how did you get from step 1 to 2? (I could figure out the transformation matrix just by looking at the reflection, but i'd like to know how to compute it....im still unsure about how you go between your two steps.

Comment: I just multiple matrix with three vectors in the first step. After that, we can solve the system to get the values of $t_{ij}$.